# View Results Table of the Jmeter script converted from LR using latest Jmeter V3.2 doesn't capture all calls

Tags: jmeter

When i tried to convert the LR script into Jmeter using Jmeter latest version 3.2 View results Table doesn't captures all calls , where as Summary Report  as well as under Thread group>Recording Controller I can see all the calls.

How does it effects means. If I cannot see the calls in the View Results Tables ,I cannot do correlation, parameterization etc for the missing calls.

Does any one has encountered this wearied issue.

Note: Jmeter V3.1 works perfectly !

Please advise me!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: If I understand your question correct, I guess you need to re-visit your approach on recording. The best approach would be is to use an "HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder" in the Workbench and go from there.Try seeing this link : https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes,that's the way I am converting.please look at the 1st screenshot, I have been doing this way successfully usingV3.1.

Comment: My bad. I didn't really read the "Recording Controller" part in the doc. I've posted a solution below. Lets see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug.
As per the issue that was opened:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61014

Starting with JMeter version 3.2 the number of results in View Results Tree is limited by default to 500 entries.

If you want more entries, you have to set the property:

> view.results.tree.max_results

to a higher value, or to "0", if you don't want to impose any limit.

You can set the property in bin/user.properties

**But be aware that this involves less responsiveness of JMeter during Load Test.**

More info might be found at:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

1. Add "HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder" under the workbench.
2. Add "View Test Results Tree" under the "HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder".
3. In the "HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder" config, select the following options: Target Controller: "Workbench > HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder" & Grouping: "Put each group in a new Transaction Controller".
4. Start the recorder, finish recording, and stop the recorder.
5. Add a "Thread Group" under the "Test Plan" and you can drag/copy the Transaction controllers to the Test Plan.

Note: The "Grouping" option would really depend on how you would like to configure your transactions however this is a recommended approach during recording.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: As I confirmed earlier this is the approach meaning what you have mentioned followed and has been following in previous versions and able to do successfully,but not able to using latest version

Comment: I got an idea! Let me try and let you know the outcome!

Comment: Do post your alternative irrespective of the outcome

Comment: This is  regression issue escalated ticket!